# Split JSON payloads into multiple lines

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have a requirement where in multiple JSON payload records are generated in one line in a file(no new line character at end, Exact JSON record is too long to add here).

Example: sample.json (received from source)
[{complex-json-record1},{complex-json-record2},{complex-json-record3},{complex-json-record4}...]

is there a way to add line-breaker (new line) character in Python/PySpark/Pandas after each JSON record?

So that at least I can get one record per line.

Still working on converting that JSON to Hive table.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the JSON spec, you can effectively insert any whitespace between tokens. There's an algorithm for that called pretty-printing, maybe that's what you're after. There are tools for the browser to display JSON in a human-readable way, e.g. JSONDiscovery. On the commandline there is `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json
print(json.dumps({"key1": 42, "key2": 142}, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Comment: Awesome trick and solved big problem, Thank you so much.

Comment: I have different requirement now, Need to get one JSON record per line (instead of splitting one JSON record into multiple lines).
{rec1},{rec2},{rec3} // All JSON records are in line
{rec1}, // complete JSON rec-1 record in one line.
{rec2}, // complete JSON rec-2 record in one line.
{rec3} // complete JSON rec-2 record in one line.

Comment: data=[{"key1": 42, "x": 1},{"key2": 142, "x": 2},{"key3": 142, "x": 3}]
to
{"key1": 42, "x": 1}
{"key2": 142, "x": 2}
{"key3": 142, "x": 3}

I used below code but I need to re-write, which is not efficient, Since I receive data file from source and I just need to format it when flatten it to store data into Hive.

with open('/home/h015851/tst.json', 'w') as f:
...     for datum in data:
...         f.write(json.dumps(datum))
...         f.write("\n")

Comment: You can load your JSON into python object with `mydata = json.loads()` and then iterate the list. Something like this:
import json


mydata = json.loads(myjsondata)
for item in mydata:
    print(json.dumps(item))

Comment: Finally, my requirement worked and I got the expected output... Thank you Sir.
'''
>>> custJsonTableDF = spark.sql(cust_json_query).repartition(500)
>>> data=str(custJsonTableDF.select(col('json_string')).first()[0])
>>> mydata = json.loads(data)
>>> res = "json_str" + "\n"
>>> for item in mydata: res = res + str(item) + "\n"
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import io
>>> val = io.StringIO(res)
>>> df = pd.read_csv(val, sep='\+s')
>>> df1=spark.createDataFrame(df)
'''